# Nsurl error domain (1012) subscribing MDM Server

Tags: macos, ipad, osx-server, certificate, mobile-device-management

I'm trying to **manage iPads** with an own **MDM-server**. I configured the ProfileManagement but it doesn't work (anymore).. I always get an **Nsurl error domain 2012** when trying to prepare the iPad (on the device). I searched a lot on the internet.. It seems to be with https? Certificates? But nothing specific for Profile Manager / MDM. 
So I don't have any idea what to do right now.

I'm preparing the iPads with Apple Configurator 2 (Version 2.2). I created a blueprint with the following settings for MDM:

- **Configuration**: Manual
- **Server**: https://mdmserver.domainname.be/devicemanagement/mdm/dep_mdm_enroll
  (When I visit this URL in the browser, I get 405 Method Not Supported : GET)
- ...

There are a lot of certificates for the server, and maybe its because they aren't the good ones..

I don't have any Certificate for https://domainname.be..

Certificates of the server:
[image: Certificates Server]

macServer > Messages (APN) (VPP appleid added):

```
mdmserver.domainname.be - apns:com.apple.calendar
mdmserver.domainname.be - apns:com.apple.contact
mdmserver.domainname.be - apns:com.apple.mail
mdmserver.domainname.be - apns:com.apple.mgmt
mdmserver.domainname.be - apns:com.apple.alerts
```

Under ProfileManager, I can add certificate.. But don't know how (where to download/find) and which one I have to use?
[image: Add Certificate]
[image: Options]

---

More additional information

**Mac version**: OS X El Capitan (10.11.4)

**OS X Server**: Server 5.1

**Hostname**: mdmserver.domainname.be

**Computername**: macserver

**Internet**: Available on mdmserver.domainname.be

I opened port **80,443,2195,2196,1640** on the firewall (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202487)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. The problem was caused by the **certificates**.
I really needed **signed certificates** for "mdmserver.domainname.be" (Server > Certificates).

But keep in mind, it has to be with a **CSR** created by the **os server**, it's not enough to create a CSR with a CSR generator (like directadmin, ..). Thats because you can't add your own private key/csr, the server has its own.

More information about the certificates install: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-mac-osx-mavericks.htm
SSL Installation Diagnostics Tool: https://www.digicert.com/help/